# How to force GCD perform current blocks on main queue?

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I have worker thread task that published results on **main** queue using:

```
// on worker queue

// (long-running task)

// publish results on main queue
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    _finished = YES;
});
```

How can i sit in main queue (main CXTest thread) and force gcd handle current tasks on the queue like:

```
// on main queue
while (!_finished) {
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    // TODO : force main queue to perform current blocks
}
```

The obvious solution is to set _finished in worker thread, but i can't do that for some reason (UI controls can be touched in main thread only)

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? You're blocking the main (UI) thread. Might as well run the task on that queue.

Comment: yes, i'm blocking the main thread as otherwise test is finished why worker thread is not finished and i have to wait for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pump your run loop like this:

```
while (!_finished) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
}
```

it will drain main queue eventually, setting `_finished` to `YES`.

But I'd recommend you to use an async test helper like [XCAsyncTextCase](http://premosystems.github.io/XCAsyncTestCase/), also [expecta](https://github.com/specta/expecta) has quite handy async helper. Other test frameworks may have such extensions as well.

Comment: this seems to be exactly what i need

Comment: Glad that helped! Would you be so kind to mark my answer with a big green checkmark?

Comment: There's a race condition on `_finished`.

Comment: @toasted_flakes Both loop and block are executed on main thread, so no, no races.