# Polling GCD main queue, to avoid deadlock

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock, nsrunloop

I have an iOS app, with multiple threads. In a background thread, I run some 3rd party code.
The 3rd party code will occasionally call:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
```

The callback has to be _sync, because it needs the answer and it needs to be on the main thread, because it calls `UIApplication`.

The problem occurs when I need to shut down the background thread. The shutdown originates from the UI and it also has to be sync. So, I sometimes see a deadlock.

I have tried to solve it, by the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992907/46970). Basically calling the NSRunLoop in a loop, until a flag has been set by the background thread.
Like this:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
```

However, it does not work. I can see in the debugger that the background thread is hanging on the dispatch_sync call, even though the NSRunLoop runUntilDate is called multiple times.

Here is the callstack of the background thread, which is blocked:

[image]

And here is the callstack of the main thread (it is not crashed, merely paused in the debugger):

[image]

I think it must be something about the runmodes, but I am not sure what and how to fix that.
So how can I service the GCD main queue, while the main thread is busy in a loop?

Comment: Just to clarify: "The shutdown originates from the UI and it also has to be async" probably should be "... it also has to be _sync_"?

Comment: Indeed @Tommy. Thanks for catching that. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

That `NSRunLoop` technique can work in some situations:

```
- (void)start {
    dispatch_sync(self.queue, ^{
        [self finishInTenSeconds];
        while (!self.isFinished) {
            NSLog(@"loop");
            [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1]];
        }
    });
}

- (void)finishInTenSeconds {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 repeats:false block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        self.isFinished = true;
    }];
}
```

But this technique of manually calling `run` on the main run loop while simultaneously blocking the main thread, is essentially a kludge (and a bit of an anachronism). E.g. replace the timer in `finishInTenSeconds` with GCD call, and this closure will never get called:

```
- (void)finishInTenSeconds {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.isFinished = true;
    });
}
```

The problem is that the `while` loop with the `run` call will allow the run loop to process events, but it doesn’t alter the fact that the main thread is blocked by the original `dispatch_sync` call.

Note, the particulars in your case are undoubtedly different, but hopefully this illustrates the general class of problem introduced with the `NSRunLoop` kludge.

---

The appropriate solution is to minimize synchronous calls. E.g. if you need to do something after the task on the background queue finishes, rather than calling synchronously, like so:

```
dispatch_sync(self.queue, ^{
    [self foo];
});

[self bar];
```

You would instead dispatch asynchronously, and then, when it’s done, dispatch the subsequent code asynchronously back to the main queue:

```
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
    [self foo];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self bar];
    });
});
```